# Localization not working in .NET Maui Android project in combination with installing nuget package

Tags: android, .net, maui, nuget-package, resx

I have 2 projects:

- A library project (Home.BudgetPlanner.Data) containing some resource files with strings in the folder Localization. For example: TransactionType.resx and TransactionType.nl-BE.resx containing both the strings Expense and Income. This project is exported as a package.
- A .NET Maui project (Home.BudgetPlanner.Mobile) with platforms Android and Windows. In this project the library package is installed.

But, when when the culture is set to nl-BE in my .NET Maui project, and I want to retrieve the dutch value of Home.BudgetPlanner.Data.Localization.TransactionType.Expense, I get the default english string.

```
cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

var x = Home.BudgetPlanner.Data.Localization.TransactionType.Expense; // english string but expecting dutch value
```

This problem happens only on the Android platform. When I deploy to the Windows platform there is no problem.

Also, it looks like it is a package related problem in combination with Android. The problem only happens when I install Home.BudgetPlanner.Data as a package in my .NET Maui project. When I manually add a reference to the exported Home.BudgetPlanner.Data.dll (using project reference) it works.

When I add resource files in .NET Maui project itself, localization works also. So I think this problem is specific a combination of Android and localization in a package.

Does anyone else have this same problem?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.6.2.

I have checked if resource file names and content are correct.

Added in csproj file:

```
<GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>true</GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>
```

Added ConfigChanges.Locale in Android MainActivity class:

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, AllowEmbedded = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Locale | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity

Tested it also on a physical device, with the same result.
I also changed the language of my device to dutch without any result. I have added also next to nl-BE, nl resource files, maybe because my phone was set to nl instead of nl-BE. But that did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue on the Github and you can refer to this issue [.Net MAUI Localization](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5595) and follow it up.

In addition, someone who met this problem mentioned that the Localization did not work when he built it in the debug mode. You can check this isssue about [Localization via satellite assemblies doesn't work for android when the app built in debug mode.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4470)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I did not know, but it works in release mode. And that's fine for me!